# Verify Your Identity - Invalid Phone #

Tags: login, login-errors, identity

Have successfully reset my login on several occasions, but this time was different. Cleared my Chrome browsing data (all of it) and that appears to have triggered my inability to log back into my developer org. Received "Please check your username and password" so tried the following

1. Clicked "Forgot PW"
2. Receive "support@salesforce.com email" and click link.
3. Answer the security question and when I click continue receive the following dead-end screen.

[image: VerifyID]

It is a dead-end because when I click on "Verify" button nothing happens. In the past I would receive an SMS with code. Not so this time. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any other computer/browser/IDE that has connected in the past?

Comment: Unfortunately @NickCook, I've not logged in from other devices. Have tried IE browser and my iOS device as an attempt. No luck. Yours was a solid idea though, thanks. Any others?

Comment: Has Salesforce added a country code (eg. +1) to your mobile number?  I think having the "+1" there is related to the problem, but have not proved it yet.  BTW, your admin can validate the last IP addr you used.  It's not an ideal solution, but it does fix the immediate problem.

Comment: Appreciate the analysis @Jagular. Unfortunately this is a developer account (which I happen to have used for over 1 year). Don't want to start a new account, and yet if I am unable to login cannot make the necessary changes on the backend.

Comment: Salesforce support may be able to help you regain access to a dev account.